# Dialogflow fulfillment two requests in te same intent

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, dialogflow-es, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I need to make two requests for a simply intent. The user response some questions and I do these two requests to same API with a diferent parameter.

I tried several things and on the last try I use a Promisse to make these two requests and return data.

**These function execute my put and get the return:**

```
async function getData(url, config, body) {
        let result = await axios.put(url, body, config);
        let returnValues = [];
        
        if(result.data){
            if (Array.isArray(result.data)) {
                result.data.forEach(item => {             
                    returnValues.push(item.message);
                });
            } else {
                returnValues.push(result.data.message);
            }
        }
        
        return returnValues;
    }
```

**These function is my handler**

```
function getDocumentHandler(agent){   
    const url = 'https://myUrl';
    const authorization = 'myBasicAuth';
    const dateformat = 'YYYYMMDD';

    const config = {
        headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Basic ' + authorization ,
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
    };

    const value = agent.parameters.value1;
    const flag = agent.parameters.flag;

    var xmlBody = '<value>' + value + '</value>';
    

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        getData(url, config, xmlBody).then(
            (res) => {
                if(res != null && res.length > 0){
                    console.log('Values without flag: ', res.length);
                    res.forEach(item => {
                        console.log('Item: ' , item);
                        agent.add(item);
                    });
                }
            }
        );

        if(flag){
            xmlBody += ' <flag>true</flag>';

            getData(url, config, xmlBody).then(
                (res) => {
                    if(res != null && res.length > 0){
                        console.log('Values with flag: ', res.length);
                        res.forEach(item => {
                            console.log('Item: ' , item);
                            agent.add(item);
                        });
                    }
                }
            );
        }

        resolve();
    });   
}
```

**Important information:**

- When I execute this code in a "Node Project" then works and console log's correctly
- When I execute in DialogFlow, I see console log by Google Console but not see in the agent.

Anyone can help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

When an intent handler returns a promise, your `WebhookClient` will create a webhook response based on the response that you added using the `add()` function, and then send it to your agent once the promise is fulfilled.

In your case, the promise that is returned by your intent handler is being fulfilled even if your `getData()` promise handlers containing the agent.add()are not yet fulfilled, as your `getData()` functions are not awaited before calling the `resolved()` function to fulfill the promise return by your intent handler. Therefore, your WebhookClient will be unable to create a response to be sent back to your agent as there will be no responses defined.

There are two ways to fix this problem. The first one is by calling the `resolved()` function of the returned promise of your intent handler inside of your `getData()` promise handlers.

```
return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        await getData(url, config, xmlBody).then(
            (res) => {
                if(res != null && res.length > 0){
                    console.log('Values without flag: ', res.length);
                    res.forEach(item => {
                        console.log('Item: ' , item);
                        agent.add(item);
                    });
                }
            }
        );

        if(flag){
            xmlBody += ' <flag>true</flag>';

            await getData(url, config, xmlBody).then(
                (res) => {
                    if(res != null && res.length > 0){
                        console.log('Values with flag: ', res.length);
                        res.forEach(item => {
                            console.log('Item: ' , item);
                            agent.add(item);
                        });
                    }
                    resolve();
                }
            );
        }
}
```

And the second one is by adding the `async` keyword in your promise handler and the `await` keyword when calling your getData function inside your promise handler.

```
return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        await getData(url, config, xmlBody).then(
            (res) => {
                if(res != null && res.length > 0){
                    console.log('Values without flag: ', res.length);
                    res.forEach(item => {
                        console.log('Item: ' , item);
                        agent.add(item);
                    });
                }
            }
        );

        if(flag){
            xmlBody += ' <flag>true</flag>';
            await getData(url, config, xmlBody).then(
                (res) => {
                    if(res != null && res.length > 0){
                        console.log('Values with flag: ', res.length);
                        res.forEach(item => {
                            console.log('Item: ' , item);
                            agent.add(item);
                        });
                    }
                }
            );
        }

        resolve();
}
```

When you `await` a promise, the function is paused in a non-blocking way until the promise is fulfilled.

However, if your fulfillment code is deployed using Dialogflow’s inline editor, note that the inline editor does not support async functions.